# Vuetify data-table supress click on row in cell

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to show a dialog if I click on a row in a vuetiy v-data-table.
Furthermore I have one column in this table which has a button that I want to use as well.

If I click this button the click on the row and the button is registered. Both functions are executed. Is there a way to not execute the click on the row?

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" @click:row="openRecipe">
  <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
    <v-icon
     small
     @click="edit(item)"
    >mdi-pencil</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add `stop` (which stops propagation of the click event) to your button's click listener like this: `@click.stop="edit(item)"`. You might want to add `prevent` as well. `@click.stop.prevent`;

More on this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)